# ScaleTransform and CenterX

Tags: wpf, scaletransform

I have the following code

```
<Canvas Width="800" Height="600">
    ...
    <local:UpgradeLandDialog x:Name="upgradeDialog" Canvas.Left="250" Canvas.Top="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0">
        <local:UpgradeLandDialog.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" ScaleY="0" CenterX="400" CenterY="300"/>
        </local:UpgradeLandDialog.LayoutTransform>
    </local:UpgradeLandDialog>
</Canvas>
```

In the UserControl I animate the ScaleTranform to 1. I want UserControl to "grow" from its center, but it "grows" from the upper left corner of it. The values in CenterX and CenterY do nothing. How can I make it Scale as I want?

Comment: I found the solution, use `RenderTransform` instead of `LayoutTransform`

Comment: Using `RenderTransform` instead of `LayoutTransform` isn't "the solution", that's just a workaround. They are responsible for 2 different things, so if I'm restricted to use `LayoutTransform`, I'm not helped out.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"` on the control you want to animate.

Comment: LayoutTransform and RenderTransform do two different things.  If you need LayoutTransform then this is not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your code like this:

```
<Canvas Width="800" Height="600" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <local:UpgradeLandDialog x:Name="upgradeDialog" Canvas.Left="250" Canvas.Top="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0">
        <local:UpgradeLandDialog.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" ScaleY="0"/>
        </local:UpgradeLandDialog.LayoutTransform>
    </local:UpgradeLandDialog>
</Canvas>
```

Remove `(CenterX="400" CenterY="300")` and add `(RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5")` to the Canvas. This way if you have a container with dynamic width and height, it can scale from the center without problem.

Answer (score 1):

To make it grow from its center, you'll have to animate its margins as well (at half the rate at which you animate the width and height).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem not too long ago as well. I ended up repositioning the user control at every layout update to simulate a custom point based growth.

Comment: I think there are better ways to do this.

Comment: How would you calculate the amount you need to move the user control?

Answer (score 0):

This does work for me. Did I miss something?

```
<Rectangle StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" Width="200" Height="200">    
  <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform 
       ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}" 
       ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}"
       CenterX ="100" CenterY="100"/>
  </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old post, I thought I'd share my findings, since it took me way too long to figure out this fairly simple solution.

Flipping the y-axis was easy, but I couldn't get CenterX and CenterY working. I really needed to be able to set the origin at any position I wanted.

Solution: nested canvasses.

```
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Canvas Canvas.Left="{Binding MyOriginLeft}" Canvas.Bottom="{Binding MyOriginBottom}">
        <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1"/>
        </Canvas.LayoutTransform>

        <!-- This now does what you expect it to do, independent of position of origin -->
        <Line X1="10" Y1="20" X2="30" Y2="40" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```